# Calculate swipe area in touchevent

Tags: android, swipe

I am calculating the swipe area in android tab. Requirement is that when user swipes on the top 10% of the screen in tab a popup should come.

How can i achieve it by using the touch event of onFling();

Right now I am doing it like below, (arg0 and arg1 are Motion events)

```
int height = this.webview.getHeight();
float x = arg0.getRawX();
float y = arg0.getRawY();
float x2 = arg1.getRawX();
float y2 = arg1.getRawY();

if (x < 2000.00 && x2 < 2000.00 && y < 200.00 && y2 < 80.00) {
showPopUp();
}
```

But, I dont want to use the hardcoded values like 2000.00 or 80.00. Instead of this the swipe should be calculated based on the device height. Though this is working fine.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can put transparent image in the area where you want(top 10 %in your case) to listen the touch and set touch listener to that image only..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int height = this.webview.getHeight();
int width = this.webview.getWidth();

float maxHeight = height*.10f; //10% of 1000 is 100
float maxWidth = width*.10f; //10% of 500 is 50

float x = arg0.getRawX();
float y = arg0.getRawY();
float x2 = arg1.getRawX();
float y2 = arg1.getRawY();

if (x > 0 && x2 < maxWidth && y > 0 && y2 < maxHeight) {
  showPopUp();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen height via [WindowManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html)

```
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();

    display.getSize(size);

    // This is the height of the screen
    size.y;
```

You can then easily use that to determine if a swipe is in the top 10%.

Depending on where you're needing to calculate the height, you could cache this value in a member (in onResume() for an Activity) so that it gets updated when the config changes (device rotation, etc.)